# PowerShell Output differences

Tags: powershell

When writing commands on powershell sometimes the output is propagated one way and sometimes the other way.
Let's say I am using the command

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | ? {$_.name -eq "$name"}
```

in that situation I can use the `Where-Object` as below, and sometimes there are commands the populating the results other way and for some reason the `Where-Object` is not working.

After investigating a little bit I found that `Select-String` will work for me for the other command that ran instead of the `Where-Object`.

So it got me wondering what could be the differences between these two outputs?

Thank you

And by the way, if someone has a good learning site that can teach me the basics of all powershell from more inside perspective like what the difference between array and hash table, that that i know already, not really basic stuff :)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of a command with which you can't use `Where-Object` but where `Select-String` seems to due the trick?

Comment: Hmm... apparently i managed to use Where-Object also on the command that i couldn't before :)

Answer (score 2):

`Where-Object` works on a collection of objects returning those objects that match a given criteria. `Select-String` works on a collection of strings returning those strings that match a given expression. They're similar in that they allow you to filter a collection of *stuff*. The stuff you can filter for one is a little different than the other. Where-Object can filter objects based on string properties or properties that cast into strings. It can also apply filters using math operators (greater than, less than, modulus etc.) to numeric properties, object comparisons, etc.

Let’s say I’ve got a file named `.gitignore`. If I wanted to see lines that included the phrase "paket", I'd write something like this:

```
cat .gitignore | select-string 'paket'
```

Select-String finds me the line or lines with the phrase I'm looking for. I can do the same thing with `Where-Object`:

```
cat .gitignore | where { $_ -like '*paket*' }
```

In this case, the object being filtered just happens to be a string so `Select-String` and `Where-Object` look pretty similar.

Now, let's create a list of dates...

```
$stuff = 1..10 | foreach { $(Get-Date).AddHours($(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 25) * -1) }
```

We’ll filter the list of dates by hour, where hour is greater than 18 (6 PM):

```
$stuff | Where-Object { $_.Hour -gt 18 }
```

In this example, we applied a math expression (greater than) to an object's property. This is something `Select-String` wouldn't do. `Where-Object` will also work on values that don't cast to a string.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: First of all thank you for your clarification, that basically what I needed to know.  But there is one script line that I don't really understand: 
 $stuff = 1..10 | foreach { $(Get-Date).AddHours($(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 25) * -1) } I know how to use foreach and variables, but can you please explain me that chunk: $(Get-Date).AddHours($(Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 25) * -1) * Why are you adding $ before the command? * And what is * sign means in powershell? Thank you.                  Apparently I can't do line breaker for some reason, so sorry about that :(

Comment: The asterisk (*) is the multiplication operator in Powershell. The bit with the dollar sign and parenthesis is a subexpression: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions/. I'm telling Powershell execute the command or expression inside the parenthesis and provide its output to the containing command.

Answer (score 0):

OK,
Apparently I managed to also use the Where-Object to filter a command results.
It's because my result was a 3 strings in every row, so using "-eq" wasn't working and giving me a blank result.
I changed it to -match or -like ** and it did find the **row** that had the string I was looking for.

For more clarification, the command I was using is "net users /domain" - it outputs the results with 3 strings in every row.

So thank you for you answers :)